# Exception NoClassDef founderror android

Tags: android

I have impelemented the actionbar using fragementactivity for view pager action bar using swipe working fne in api leve1 17 or above but coming to the lower version 2.2 to 4.0.3 it showing noclassdef error it is tourching so much please help me to how to retify this code pls help....
target version is 17 The person who solves answer i wll give party dnt miss my party get ready for answer

this is my code

```
public class Cbntabs extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener{

private ViewPager viewPager;
private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
 ActionBar actionBar;
String result;
// Tab titles
private String[] tabs = { "CBN Voice", "CBN Message" };


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.tabs);

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
     if(bundle!=null)
     {
         result=bundle.getString("results");

     }

    // Initilization
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    actionBar = getActionBar();
    mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),result);
    /**/
     actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

     actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
               actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.header_bg));
     actionBar.setTitle("TELUGU DESAM PARTY  ELITE CLUB");
     View customNav = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_show_action_bar, null);
    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Comment: which library you used for fragment activity?

Comment: import android.support.v4.app.Fragment has user

Comment: try to import "appcompat_v7" library in to your project. you can download this library from https://github.com/koush/android-support-v7-appcompat

Comment: if it works means it will party to u

Comment: Hey but both fragamentactivity,action bar extends hw?

Comment: what i am not getting?

Comment: remove import android.support.v4.app.Fragment then import v7 support... understand?

Comment: did have sample app which is using import v7 please send

Comment: hey i am getting error while adding import android.support.v4

Comment: which error you are getting?

Comment: appcompat_v7_3] Unable to resolve target 'android-19'

Answer (score 0):

you should use getSupportActionBar.

just import the library project into your workspace 
Path to import project is : Android SDK -> Extras -> android ->support - > v7 -> appcompat and the after importing this project right click on your project -> select properties -> android -> add library and he just add the imported library here